# Array of Objects Built Inside Functions has Type Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm making nested API calls and putting pieces of the result in an array of objects. When I print this out to the console, it looks fine. But when I try to call functions on the pieces, they break.

Here's the code except for the private API URL:

```
var gate = new Array();

jQuery.getJSON(endPoint + "method=GetUsersWithTicketsEventId", function(tickets) {
  jQuery.each(tickets.message, function(i, ticket) {
    gate[i] = new Object();

    jQuery.getJSON(endPoint + "method=GrabUsersCustomEventInfo&userId=" + ticket.UserId, function(answers) {
        jQuery.each(answers.message, function(j, answer) {
        if (answer.meta_key == "42_Volunteering") {
          if (answer.meta_value != "Array") {
            gate[i].Roles = answer.meta_value.split(';');
          } else {
            gate[i].Roles = new Array();
          }
        } else if (answer.meta_key == "42_1_TOSDate") {
            gate[i].Date = new Date(answer.meta_value);
        }

        console.dir(gate[0].Date); // This works
      });  
    });

  });

  console.dir(gate); // This works
  console.dir(gate[0].Date); // This returns undefined
});
```

The results of the second console.dir() seem to be well formed:

```
> Array(237)
  > [0 … 99]
    > 0: Object
      > Date: Mon May 08 2017 21:09:09 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
        > __proto__: Object
          > constructor: function Date()
...
```

I assume this has something to do with variable scope, but I don't understand how to debug it when the console output is so obviously different from what the interpreter is seeing.

Comment: It's an async issue. `console.dir(gate[0].Date);` runs before the objects have been built.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your code:

```
console.dir(gate); // This works:
```

because you have defined your object previously and you are telling the console to print out the object which will update as more data comes in.

```
console.dir(gate[0].Date); // This returns undefined
```

This returns undefined because at this point in the execution, the array is actually empty. Your inner fetch hasn't filled in the object yet so it's an undefined reference.

Comment: Oooh, because getJSON is asynchronous!! So how can I architect this kind of thing to accommodate that?

Comment: Look into using promises to wait until everything is done.